# converting bmp to jpg in java

Tags: java, jpeg, bmp

How do you convert bmp to jpg in Java? I know how to use the `ImageIO` way but is there a much faster or better way of doing it?

This is the ImageIO way of doing that I found on the web.

```
`//Create file for the source  
File input = new File("c:/temp/image.bmp");  

//Read the file to a BufferedImage  
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);`

//Create a file for the output  
File output = new File("c:/temp/image.jpg");  

//Write the image to the destination as a JPG  
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", output);
```

If I use this way will I lose quality?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using PNG over JPG. You'll still get a much smaller image than a BMP, but without losing image quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you will. Actually regardless of the way to convert a BMP (lossless) to JPG (lossy) you always lose quality. You can limit the damage if you set the JPG quality to 100% (which kind of defeats the purpose in my opinion).

Use this [tutorial](http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/java/adjust-jpeg-image-compression-quality-when-saving-images-in-java) to fix it.